# Using output of an aws cli command as an input for another command

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I have been trying to use output of the `list-backup-plans` to use as input for `get-backup-plan --backup-plan-id`. I tried this command but it seems inappropriate for multiple backup plan ids. Could someone address me what correct command can be used?

```
aws backup list-backup-plans --query BackupPlansList[*].BackupPlanId | xargs -I {} aws backup get-backup-plan --backup-plan-id {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to specify the `--output` option, and replace tabs with newlines:

```bash
aws backup list-backup-plans --query 'BackupPlansList[*].BackupPlanId' --output text | tr "\t" "\n" | xargs -I {} aws backup get-backup-plan --backup-plan-id {}
```